# How to get/access/reference pages in a directory with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Github Pages site using Jekyll. I have a directory with subdirectories and posts, like this:

```
/
  documentation/
    powershell/
      get-service.md
      invoke-webrequest.md
```

I also have an `index.md` file at the root of `/documentation/` as a landing page. I want to list all the posts (in this case, `get-service.md` and `invoke-webrequest.md`) as a list on `index.md`.

By default, the homepage of the site already does this with anything in the `/_posts/` directory with something like this:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts %}
{%- for post in posts -%}
  ...some html...
{%- endfor -%}
```

But the contents of `/_posts/` are automatically assigned to the `site.posts` variable, so how would I do the same with the contents of `/documentation/`, which is not automatically assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`site.pages`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables), which contains all pages of the site. This includes the Atom feed, the 404 page, and others; to filter only the ones in a specific directory, you could filter by path:

```
{% assign pages = site.pages
  | where_exp:"item", "item.path contains 'documentation/powershell/'" %}
{% for page in pages %}
- [{{ page.title }}]({{ page.url | absolute_url }})
{%- endfor %}
```